# Simple Array Sum

Tags: python, python-3.x

When I run my code in python IDLE it works. But when I run my code on  HackerRank I get a ValueError. What can I do?

```py
list=[]
n=int(input())
sum=0
for i in range(0,n):
    app=int(input())
    list.append(app)
for j in list:   
    sum=sum+j
print(sum)
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Solution.py", line 5, in <module>
    app=int(input())
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '1 2 3 4 10 11'
```

Comment: In Python `list` is a type.  If you use it for a name you can confuse things.

Comment: As said by @StephenRauch, you cannot use int() to covert a `list`. Besides, online platforms have a lot of problems with STDIN and STDOUT formats. It might be that that you're using the wrong type for a correct input.

Comment: The Python `input()` function inputs an entire line of text.  So if you want to input 6 numbers, you have to enter them one per line.  If you enter them all on a single line, then you end up with a single space-separated string, as you saw.  So of course you get an error when you pass it to `int`.

Comment: This code works if `input()` returns a string containing a single integer such as `'5'`, but not when it contains many integers such as in your example.

Comment: Check the requirements of that HackerRank problem. If I remember correctly, some of them will pass a list of numbers as input, not 1 number at a time. If you try passing in "1 2 3 4 10 11" as input on IDLE, you will get the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

In Hackerrank generally your list will be a space generated value so for that you can use this snippet, you can go through map concept in python "http://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/map_filter.html"

```
n = int(input())

li = map(int, input().split())

sum = 0

for i in li:
   sum += i
print (sum)
```

Comment: .split() will split on any whitespace by default, so you don't need to include the space.

Comment: yeah I removed that thanks